# change the status of the power saver (on/off)

Tags: java, android, android-intent

i have tried to change the status of the power saver  mode from my app i have figured out how to read the status (Through the Power Manager) but how can i change  it

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
```

`PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag")`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Guess There is no API in android SDK to support this, Because power saver might be a third party function given by the device manufactures company and they have there own version of "Power Savers" . You can just use the PowerManager to acquire and release wakelocks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `wl.acquire();` and make sure you have this permission added to your manifest,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```